# How to access object from another tab c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol on my winforms. On a tab page I have a `combobox` and on the another one I have a `datagdridview`. I need to get the text of a column of `datagridview` into `combobox`. The idea is that I don't know to have access at `datagridview` . It says that it is not in the current context.

This is how I have tried:

```
private void GetTextGrid()
    {
        combobox1.DataSource = gridview1.DataSource;
        combobox1.DisplayMember = "Column1";
        combobox1.ValueMember = "Column1";
    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with it being on a different tab. All that switching tabs does is toggle an objects visibility.

Comment: Weird, by using comboBox1.SelectedItem (or similiar) you should be able to access it.

Comment: Please post your code where you are facing this out of context error.

Answer (score 2):

The datagridview has a DataSource set to some collection of items. Can't you just access that collection? If you dont have access to it where you need, you should easily be able to send it as a parameter.